# Is there Catholic doctrine about "divine ideas"?

Tags: catholicism, philosophy, augustine, plato, doctrine

Augustine was a staunch advocate of the ["doctrine" of divine ideas](https://jonathansmcintosh.wordpress.com/2013/05/14/augustines-doctrine-of-the-divine-ideas/), which locates Plato's exemplary forms in the mind of God. The theory seems to have been [generally adopted by Thomas Aquinas](https://muse.jhu.edu/article/361952/summary).

But did the Magisterium of the Catholic Church ever endorse the theory of divine ideas? Is the Catholic free to reject it, as Ockham effectively did?